# How to unchain asynchronous functions from delegates

Tags: c#, events, blazor, delegates, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a Blazor server project, I have a repository service from which I'm executing database operations, and I have a razor component X which consumes that service.

Basically, I want to trigger an event in the repository service on certain actions, like add, update, delete, to notify the razor component X with new changes.
Here is the event declaration in the repository service:

```
Public event Action? SomethingChanged;
```

and I'm invoking that event on every crud operation.
In the component X I'm chaining that event (from the repository service) with an asynchronous method, which works fine if I execute it with the following syntax:

```
protected override OnInitalized()
{
    RepositoryService.SomethingChanged += async () => await AnAsynchronousMethod();
}
```

My problem is that I cannot unchain that asynchronous method from the event since, as far as I know the following code :

```
public void Dispose()
{
    RepositoryService.SomethingChanged -= async () => await AnAsynchronousMethod();
}
```

will not be able to unchain the asynchronous method (since the anonymous method will try to create another method under the hood).

Maybe you'll find it irrational to use an event for receiving notification for updates, but the reason is that I'm doing that, is because I'm injecting that repository service in another component Y.
And changes made with the repository service in component Y needs to take effect in the actual component X.

Is there any way to overcome this problem, or is there any other approach that you think is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a method so that you can use a method group conversion instead of a lambda expression. Given that the event is declared with a delegate type of `Action` (so synchronous) you'd want something like this:

```cs
protected override OnInitalized() =>
    RepositoryService.SomethingChanged += InitializationHandler;

public void Dispose() =>
    RepositoryService.SomethingChanged -= InitializationHandler;

// Note: async void is normally an antipattern, but it's common
// for event handlers.
private async void InitializationHandler() =>
    await AnAsynchronousMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you, that works fine, but 'async void' method signature will cause some problems, like loosing stack trace.
Do you think I should be concerned about this if so, do you recommend any other approaches to tackle the problem I've described above, a more elegant way.

Comment: @YoussefBennourSahli: Do you believe it will cause problems that the lambda expression didn't cause? The lambda expression was basically doing the same thing... this is just an artifact of calling an async method from a synchronous method.

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler:

```cs
protected override void OnInitalized()
{
    RepositoryService.SomethingChanged += AnAsynchronousMethod;  // no ()
}

public void Dispose()
{
    RepositoryService.SomethingChanged -= AnAsynchronousMethod;
}
```

You don't want to call the method when subscribing, omtting the `()` is similar to `address-of`. And async/await can be left out too.

`AnAsynchronousMethod()` can (should) be an `async void`. Your code suggests that it returns a Task but it is not possible (reliable) to await that when raising the event.

---

> I'm using an event of type Action

Then you will indeed have to wrap it.

```
async void UpdateHandler() // for += and -=
{
  await InvokeAsync(AnAsynchronousMethod);
  await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I'm using an event of type Action, so it doesn't accept it that way.

Comment: It does work with the async void one, but if I'm going to to chain an 'async Task' directly it won't be possible since I'm using an Aciton, In that case I should switch to a type of a delegate that has a return type.